# How to effectively replace (mysql_result(mysql_query()) in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As my process is almost complete for rewriting web with PDO instead of `mysql_*` commands I am now testing my changed functions. And It seems that my changed function for `mysql_result(mysql_query()` always returns true, why is that? Lets see original and changed code:

```
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE id='".$_SESSION["user_id"]."' AND online=1"), 0)>0)
{
  return true; 
}
else
  return false;
```

And changed code here:

```
$stmt = $db_login->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE id=:id AND online=1");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $_SESSION["user_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$results_login = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rows = count($results_login);
if ($rows > 0)
{
  return true; 
}
else
  return false;
```

So what is wrong with is why it always returns true even when column has online=0? Thank you

Comment: @tereško so in my case it would be $rows = count(array(0)); ?

Comment: please, go and learn php, instead of blindly copy-pasting code

Comment: In my learning books there is always mysql_* commands :( so I am trying to learn PDO and system of it on my own :) and I already know that count returns big number from the answe so i dont get it why you posted it here :)

Comment: @Byakugan: If you see somthing is in error, try to locate the error. Not just broadly asking. I can understand however, if you change to something new, that it is harder to locate the point of error. But nevertheless, try to find "the one point" how the error happens with debugging, like using `var_dump($results_login);` and such.

Comment: OK thnk you will do :) I just thought it could happen to other people and could be usefull to somebody in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stmt->fetch` fetches *one row* from the result set. What you get out of that is an array containing all the selected columns, looking something like this:

```
array(
    'COUNT(*)' => 42
)
```

A `count()` on that array will always result in `1`.

You need to check the contents of the fetched row:

```
if ($result_login['COUNT(*)'] > 0)
```

It's best to alias this column to a nicer name:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` ...
```

Then:

```
if ($result_login['count'] > 0)
```

Comment: When I want this to be real rows count what should I use? For example looking for how many times online=1 in every accounts and compairing them what should I use? For intance when I search if there is more than 50 accounts online what check function I should use instead of this mysql_result?

Comment: You are already `SELECT`ing the `COUNT()`. This will always result in *one* row with the data you want. That means you are letting the database do the counting. The alternative would be to simply `SELECT` all rows (no `COUNT()`), then check using [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) how many rows you fetched. That's quite a wasteful operation though.

Comment: What would be the case if I choose SELECT * FROM command and want to know number of rows in result - can I just use $result_login['*'] ? Thank you